# Unable to pass data from activity to another

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

My first Activity debugs corrects outputs of location name and address, however the second Activity gives me a null value. Would anyone help please?

**FirstActivity**

```
mySavedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent next = new Intent(MyDestination.this, MyLocationDetail.class);
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        String locationName = myList.get(position).getLocation_name();
        String address = myList.get(position).getAddress();
        extra.putString("extra_location", locationName);
        extra.putString("extra_address", address);

        Log.d(TAG, "name is " + locationName);
        Log.d(TAG, "address is "+ address);
        intent.putExtras(extra);
        startActivity(next);
    }
});
```

**SecondActivity**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String locationName = b.getString("extra_location");
String address = b.getString("extra_address");
Log.d(TAG, "location "+locationName);
```

Comment: `next.putExtras(extra);` instead of `intent.putExtras(extra);` Where is the variable intent coming from?

Comment: oh right let me try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try get the intent first:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

then:

```
string location = intent.getStringExtra("extra_location")
```

Comment: I'm currently using Bundle to hold all possible values.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
String locationName = myList.getItemAtPosition(position).getLocation_name();String address = myList.getItemAtPosition(position).getAddress();
```